# It is childish to complain against rules

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

It is childish to complain against rules. 
Correct it where necessary? 
Find the error.

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic.

Comment: I didn't get.  What do you want to say?

Comment: In that case, please start by looking up the words "proofreading", "is", and "off-topic" in a dictionary of your liking. Thank you.

Comment: Where is Aawariya A R's explanation? It was clear.

Comment: What do you mean, it's right here on this page. Are you facing difficulties scrolling down?

Comment: Please see our [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/346/300). Specifically, "make a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* approach to answering the question". We are not here to do your homework for you with zero effort on your side. Put the same amount of work into your questions as you expect people to put into their answers. Right now you're too lazy to even formulate and punctuate your question meaningfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It is childish to complain **against** rules.*

The error lies in the preposition. The verb *complain* is generally followed by          to, of or about.

**complain to**:

> to grouch or protest to someone

**complain of**:

> to say that something bad has happened.

For example, *Refugees had complained of being robbed and beaten by officials.*

> to say that you have a pain or are ill.

For example, *She’d been complaining of headaches*.

**complain about**:

> to protest someone or something; to grouch about someone or something.

For example, *You are always complaining about me.*

The noun, *complaint* is *generally* followed by *against*.

For example, *A **complaint** was filed **against** the thief.*

As you can see from the meanings that I've listed above, the correct option in this particular context would be *complain about*.

*It is childish to **complain about** rules.*

Comment: No problem! 'Complain against' is seen in some online dictionaries, but I've always been told that this usage is wrong. I think this explanation will answer your second question as well.